# http retry advice not retrying when an exception is thrown

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I have service activator method which throws database exception, I am catching that exception and sending ResponseEntity to the output channel. I have retry advice configured on the service activator but its doesn't retry(I am assuming its because I am catching it and sending custom exception to the output channel), I want it to retry 4 times first and then send custom exception. can you please how can I achieve it?

```
<int:chain id="a1-chain" input-channel="dRequestInputChannel" output-channel="dIntermediateChannel">
            <int:service-activator ref="dAdapterController" method="dPersist">
                <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
                    <int:retry-advice max-attempts="4" recovery-channel="dRetryChannel">
                        <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="5.0" maximum="60000" />
                    </int:retry-advice>
                </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int:service-activator>
        </int:chain>

<int:transformer input-channel="dRetryChannel" expression="payload.getFailedMessage()"/>
```

There is some piece of code after this in which I have a chain which has input channel as dIntermediateChannel and one router etc. which works fine! I meant to say flow works fine without retrying!

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself:

> I am catching that exception and sending `ResponseEntity` to the output channel.

It is not clear what made you think that retry has to work in this case: if not exception is thrown from the user code, then nothing to `catch` in the retry interceptor and therefore no trigger to initiate retry policy.

Please, don't confuse yourself and us. We don't know what is your code, but your say:

> then send custom exception

So, send it is a part of `ResponseEntity` or throw?
I would say in the first case it is just custom reply and doesn't matter what is its body. As long as it does not cause `throws` it is not an exception to `catch`.

If you want a retry and then fallback, so take a look into a logic where you don't `catch` exception yourself, but let it to be done by the `retry-advice`.

To make a custom reply, you need to look into a `RecoveryCallback` injected into a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`. Unfortunately, that `int:retry-advice` does not expose `RecoveryCallback`. An existing `recovery-channel` does not expect a reply to be produced from the publishing.

Another way is to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` around this retry to catch the final exception and produce some compensation.